# Merging two dataframes on a column and on a subset of two columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge

The question seems fairly simple but I am having a hard time about it. Idea is to merge on a common column and on either one another column OR another column. I am providing a fake example for you to understand:

```
data = {
    'From': ['1-1-2024', '2-2-2024'],
    'To': ['1-1-9999', '1-1-9999'],
    'A': ['XX', 'XX'],
    'B': ['YY', 'ZZ']
}
a = pd.DataFrame(data)
data_2 = {
    'From': ['1-1-2024', '16-1-2024'],
    'To': ['15-1-2024', '1-1-9999'],
    'A': ['XX', 'XX'],
    'C': ['LL', 'OO']
}
b = pd.DataFrame(data_2)

data_3 = {
    'From': ['1-1-2024', '16-1-2024', '2-2-2024'],
    'To': ['15-1-2024', '1-1-9999', '1-1-9999'],
    'A': ['XX', 'XX', 'XX'],
    'B': ['YY', 'YY', 'ZZ'],
    'C': ['LL', 'OO', 'OO']
}
c = pd.DataFrame(data_3)
c
```

Goal is to merge `a` and `b` with pandas to get `c`, using either `From` or `To`, combined with `A` as key.

Tried a lot of various merge and concat logic without having any good results

Comment: Please explain the logic in detail, don't make us guess it.

Comment: Logic would be merge on column 'A' and on 'From' OR 'To'

Comment: How do you explain the second row in the output?

Comment: You're correct. We will need to have 1-1-9999 on the first row of A to be able to apply what I said. Correcting the post

Comment: What is the exact expected output? Are data_1/2/3 all input data?

Comment: Sorry, one more thing that is unclear in the output, when matching on "To", do you want to keep the "From" data of `a` or `b`? It's currently not consistent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You may also provide your attempt that took you closest to your goal, even if it is unsatisfactory. Maybe a small correction could suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact logic is not fully clear, but you could perform two separate [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html); Here keeping the data from `a`:

```
out = pd.concat([a.merge(b.drop(columns='To'), on=['From', 'A']),
                 a.merge(b.drop(columns='From'), on=['To', 'A'])],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
       From        To   A   B   C
0  1-1-2024  1-1-9999  XX  YY  LL
1  1-1-2024  1-1-9999  XX  YY  OO
2  2-2-2024  1-1-9999  XX  ZZ  OO
```

If you want to keep the data from `b`:

```
out = (pd.concat([a.drop(columns='To').merge(b, on=['From', 'A']),
                  a.drop(columns='From').merge(b, on=['To', 'A'])],
                ignore_index=True)
       [a.columns.union(b.columns, sort=False)]
      )
```

Output:

```
        From         To   A   B   C
0   1-1-2024  15-1-2024  XX  YY  LL
1  16-1-2024   1-1-9999  XX  YY  OO
2  16-1-2024   1-1-9999  XX  ZZ  OO
```

You can also mix-and-match (e.g. keeping the data from `b` in `From` and `a` in `To`):

```
out = pd.concat([a.drop(columns='To').merge(b, on=['From', 'A']),
                 a.merge(b.drop(columns='From'), on=['To', 'A'])],
               ignore_index=True)[a.columns.union(b.columns, sort=False)]
```

Output:

```
        From        To   A   B   C
0   1-1-2024  1-1-9999  XX  YY  LL
1  16-1-2024  1-1-9999  XX  YY  OO
2  16-1-2024  1-1-9999  XX  ZZ  OO
```

---

A generic approach if you have more than two alternative columns. You have to adapt it depending on the desired side from which to keep the data:

```
cols = ['From', 'To']
S = set(cols)

out = pd.concat([a.merge(b.drop(columns=S.difference({col})), on=[col, 'A'])
                 for col in cols],
               ignore_index=True)
```